# PHP Session's Data is inconsistent between page reloads - the Session ID is the same though

Tags: php, session, web

I'm having a really strange problem with some of my PHP code. I have error reporting turned on and nothing's coming up either.

Basically I have a form that pushed data to $_SESSION[]. The code is:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['contact']['name'] = $_GET['name'];
$_SESSION['contact']['email'] = $_GET['email'];
$_SESSION['contact']['question'] = $_GET['question'];

session_write_close();
header('Location: confirm.php');
exit;
?>
```

This is **working**. However, completely at *random* the confirm.php will or will not recieve this data. If I refresh multiple times I sometimes get the data, sometimes not.

Here's the confirm code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(-1);

session_start();

print "SeshID:" . session_id() . "<br>";
print "CookieID:" . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "<br>";
print "Status" . session_status() . "<br>";
print "Loc" . session_save_path() . "<br>";
print "Cookie";
print_r(session_get_cookie_params());
print "<br>Data:<br>";

print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Again, no errors. Nothing appearing that looks obviously wrong.

The strange thing is that sometimes when I refresh the confirm page I will get an empty "Array ( )". Sometimes I'll get "Array ( [contact] => Array ( [question] => test [name] => [email] => test@test.com) )" for seemingly no reason...

I'm running no other scripts in between doing this - only the script above that checks the content of the session (confirm) need be re-ran and only the data somehow changes. I run the form a few times, then this check script and it's entirely inconsistent. **The session and cookie IDs never change and are always the same**

Is there some PHP setting I'm missing? It's really weird to me that these are seemingly pulling out *old* data which has been overwritten.

Comment: I would try taking out session_write_close() and giving it another try.

Comment: Are you sure that, each time you refresh the confirm.php page, $_GET parameters are still there in the url? If they are missing, $_SESSION variable won't be written for obvious reasons

Comment: Are the server part of a cluster or behind a load balancer? When data is lost, does it stay lost or does it come and go?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind, done. The problem still persists, however.

Comment: @Yuri, the confirm page is the second block of code and only reads the GET data - I'm sure it's present and saved because it _sometimes_ shows up in the data on confirm.

Comment: @DavidMårtensson, It's part of a cluster - though I'm not sure of the specific configuration as I'm just doing the PHP side of things. The data comes and goes sporadically. Is there anything in particular I should suspect? Thanks.

Comment: @TobyWilkes in that case, the first call write the session data to machine 1, and the confirm is then reading from machine 2, which doesn't have the right info. In clusters, `/tmp` is often not mirrored, and that is where the session data is stored. Talk to your cluster admin about this.

Comment: I mean, are you 100% sure that you are not overwriting those variables with empty ones? that behaviour sounds a little weird

Comment: Another option is to set the session save path to a mirrored location using http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Comment: @BartFriederichs, is there any way to determine which directories are or are not being mirrored? Thanks. I'll get in touch with our admin.

Comment: @TobyWilkes your admin will know, but you can be fairly sure that the dirs where your PHP scripts are stored, are mirrored. You could create a subdir "session_info" there. Make sure to make them writable for the webserver user.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this appears to have been the problem. If one of you guys would make it a real answer I can select it as correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solved!

I'll post my own answer for people with the same problem. Thanks to the people who helped in the comments for discovering this for me!

## The Problem

The problem was that the server was using a cluster or distribution network, mine *Azure*, to serve the PHP files.

> The first call writes the session data to machine 1, and the confirm is then reading from machine 2, which doesn't have the right info. In clusters, /tmp is often not mirrored, and that is where the session data is stored. Talk to your cluster admin about this. *– Bart Friederichs*

It seems like the *form* was being sent and having the session variables stored on server 1, but the page pulling the session data was server 2, server 3 and sometimes server 1 - hence the odd behaviour of seeing prior submissions and occasionally correct data.

## The Fix

There are two possible fixes here. One:

### The session store directory isn't being mirrored across all servers

In this case, change your session directory by changing "session.save_path" in your php.ini or by using

```
session_save_path(dirname(__FILE__). '/sessions/');
```

at the top of the affected files **before you call session_start()** (this was the ONLY part of our site that uses sessions so this made for a good / dirty fix).

The point here is to change it to a directory that is for sure being mirrored across every server in your cluster.

### The session is being saved in another way that isn't mirrored

In my actual case I found that my session handler was the problem. By using

```
phpinfo();
```

I found that my session.save_handler was "wincache", which is a plugin to speed up PHP. One of the ways it appears to do this is by using shared memory or something in order to speed up the loading of the session data.

Either way, this was not right for my setup and I fixed it by simply changing the variable to use the default: 'files'.

Again, the best way to do this is by using your **php.ini** and setting session.save_handler to "files" but I don't have access to that file and so, again, I just used a call in the header of the two files **before session_start()**.

```
ini_set("session.save_handler", "files");
```

I wouldn't recommend this as you know it's going to come up and bite you in the backside later on when a new developer comes in and you forget - it's better to change your .ini

Anyway, that was that.

Thanks everyone for your help!

### Aside

Many server solutions such as Azure actually offer their own plugins and session handlers specifically to counteract this kind of situation. If possible you should of course use them!

Comment: Regarding WinCache: You're absolutely correct: If you are in a load balanced environment with multiple workers, and you don't have client affinity enabled, then you must use a session caching mechanism that is shared by all of the workers.  WinCache's session cache is only shared amongst php-cgi processes on the same worker.  You could use `session.save_handler = files`, and point the `session.save_path` to a shared folder. Or you could use Redis or memcached as a shared cache.

Answer (score -4):

**After refreshing the page the session is still authenticated, but we lose the things we've added manually using the instruction 
try this one
(this.set('session.X', 'Y'));**